# What does the surface of equal propagation time look like in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity

If I, an inertial observer, see an event reach two points, A and B, at time t=0, what does the surface of possible source points in spacetime look like, assuming the event propagates at the speed of light?  I think it's a hyperbolic surface in some way but having a hard time visualizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint is that any source event must be in both $A$ and $B$'s past lightcones.  Hence, the potential source is the overlap between the past lightcone from $A$, and the past lightcone from $B$.

If the event is travelling at the speed of light, then it will be *on* the lightcone, and hence you are looking at the intersection of the edges of the two cones.  I've included a diagram for the 2d case.

[image]

Comment: Any idea what that surface is though?  Is it hyperbolic?

Comment: A hyperbola is the intersection of a plane and a cone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section
As all intersection points do lie on a vertical plane bisecting $\vec{AB}$ then this must be a hyperbola. (It's a line not a surface, though)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the light cones are actually hyperbolic though: $x^2+y^2+z^2-(ct)^2 = 0$, so I'm curious if it still works out the same.

Comment: I agree on the line of intersections being a hyperbola, based on the reasoning in the comment by @JMLCarter  In 3D, it becomes intersections of spheres, which would be a hyperboloid.

Comment: Light cones are (hyper)cones, since there's a zero on the RHS of that equation. Consider the Euclidean 3D case. $x^2+y^2=z^2$. That's a pair of cones whose apices touch at the origin, symmetrical about the Z axis.